# output file is generating twice for every record

Tags: perl

Can you please help me out in the below logic? I need to print the Active and status for a particular "ID" in one line. When I execute the below logic, it is printing twice for each and every ID.

I getting the output like (which is wrong)

```
Totals,,, 31,0,53

Totals,,, 0,31,53

Totals,,, 60,0,61
```

### Table contains:

```
ID         value         Days
53          ACTIVE       31
53          SUSPEND      31
61           ACTIVE       60
```

I need to see the output like

```
Totals,,, 31,31,53
Totals,,, 60,,61
```

Code:

```
while ( my ( $ID, $value, $DAYS ) = $Query->fetchrow_array() ) {
    my $activeID    = $ID;
    my $activedays  = "";
    my $suspenddays = "";

    if ($activeID) {
        if ( $value eq "ACTIVE" ) {
            $active = $DAYS;

        }
        if ( $value eq "SUSPEND" ) {
            $suspend = $DAYS;
        }
    }

    printf $OUTPUT "Totals,,,%d,%d,%d\n", $active, $suspend, $activeID;
}
```

Comment: You have the `printf` inside your `while` loop, so it will print the values for every line of input. You will probably want to create some type of hash where your keys are the `ID` and then iterate through that and print it at the end.

Comment: Or, change the query to return the active and suspend data together in one row.

Answer (score 0):

```
my %COUNT = ();
while ( my ( $ID, $value, $DAYS ) = $Query->fetchrow_array() ) {
  if ($ID) {
      # assumes active lines come before suspend lines in the table for a particular ID
      push (@$COUNT{$ID},$days);
  }
}

foreach my $key (keys %COUNT) {
  my ($active, $suspend);
  $active = $$COUNT{$key}[0] if (defined $$COUNT{$key}[0]);
  $suspend = $$COUNT{$key}[1] if (defined $$COUNT{$key}[1]);

  print "Totals,,,$active,$suspend,$key\n";  
}
```